# asp:Repeater min and max

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a webform named Default.aspx.
Her is a repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repBudget" runat="server" OnItemCreated="ItemCreated">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div>
      <label>
        <%# Eval("NameCountry") %>
       </label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="tbBudget" runat="server" TextMode="Number" 
       onKeyUp           ="tbBudgetKeyPressed(this, LowValue);" 
       AutoPostBack = "false" 
       min='<%#Eval("LowValue") %>' max='<%#Eval("TopValue") %>' 
       pattern="^[0-9]*$" required step="1" Text='<%#Eval("Filing") %>' />
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have got a handlere performed on client's side:

```
function tbBudgetKeyPressed(ida, minvalue) {
    alert(ida.value);
    document.getElementById(ida.id).blur();
    document.getElementById(ida.id).focus();
 }
```

My question is how to pass parameters **max** and  **min**

from asp:TextBox which is in repeater into tbBudgetKeyPressed. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you know the id, you can find the properties. I'm not sure what `LowValue` is in the KeyUp, so I made this example without it.

```
onKeyUp="tbBudgetKeyPressed(this)"
```

And then the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tbBudgetKeyPressed(ida) {
        var min = $('#' + ida.id).attr('min');
        var max = $('#' + ida.id).attr('max');
        console.log(min);
        console.log(max);
    }
</script>
```

Or if you do not use jQuery

```
var min = document.getElementById(ida.id).getAttribute('min');
var max = document.getElementById(ida.id).getAttribute('max');
```